# C++ - Folder of personal classes in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, class, ubuntu-16.04

Probably a stupid question, I've ben programming in C++ for some time but in comparison I'm kind of a newbie with Linux.

I created a simple Matrix class in C++, and I've been using it in most of the programs I need for work.
So far, I've been copying the Matrix.h and Matrix.cc files in a /include subfolder I create inside of the different folders containing the programs I write, compiling them and linking everything together with makefiles. Not really that smart, I guess.

Now, the first thing that came to my mind to improve the situation was to put a single copy of the Matrix.h and Matrix.cc in a folder, and to add their new path in the make files of my programs.
In this case, is there any "preferred" folder, where it should be more convenient to have the files? I seem to understand most header files are in /usr/include, while the class files are in /usr/lib.

Specifically, I was thinking that, when I'm using this class I created, I have to include the header file in the main_program.cpp AND link the file Matrix.o when compiling.
On the other hand, when I use a "normal" class (say cmath, vector, iostream) I just need to include the header in the main file, and the compiler takes care of the linking.
Can this be achieved by simply putting my class files in the right system folder? Should I modify anything in the compiler's options?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a broad question. A quick and dirty way would be to drop your file in `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`. **But** you don't want to do this, as this means your projects will be tied to the configuration of your system. The clean solution would be to build a library, either static (functions get copied into your programs when you compile) or dynamic (the library stands alone, and your programs find it dynamically when you run them). Managing this kind of things manually is error-prone though, you should use a build toolsuite (such as [CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/))

Comment: Learn to use a [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool like [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)  or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/). Configure it (with `make` by editing your `Makefile`) to compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...)

Comment: BTW, Linux don't have folders but directories. For simple projects, you don't want to have a subdirectory like your `include/` and you could put all C++ header and source files in your build directory

Comment: Also, study the source code of existing free software projects (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)...); they should inspire you!

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you don't have to manually link things form standard headers is that the compiler links `libc.a` by default. Other libraries are not linked by default and require compilation flags. For example, `cmath` requires the `-lm` flag since is not part of `libc`.

Thus, the short answer is that you can't really avoid telling the compiler what to link.